# PHP-MySQL - allow client to define process, algorithm or query

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

In my website, I allow groups of users to manage a group bank account. Users report that they payed for something the group should fund, and the group account 'pays them back'.

However, I want to give the account admin control over which user pays what and when.

For example, a group of people share a car. They open a group account to handle their car-related expenses - gas, maintenance etc.

The group admin decides that only people who drove over 20 miles this month should participate in the gas bill, and the bill is divided between the paying users (those who drove over 20 miles) proportional to their mileage (a user who drove 60 miles will pay twice as much as a user who drove 30 miles).

I have a table for `users` (a list of users, each one is part of a group account), one for `group_accounts` and one for `expense_types` (in this example, `gas` and `maintenance` are listed here)

**The question:**

Is there a good way to store **client-defined queries or algorithms in a database** to allow the admin of the group to create complex billing methods, and (using PHP) subsequently retrieving and implementing those algorithms and calculating the result?

This is a database design question, so as far as I'm concerned extra columns may be added to any table, new tables created, procedures, triggers etc.

**NOTE: THE SPECIFIC EXAMPLE IS OF NO REAL INTEREST**, I want my system to handle algorithms of unknown complexity that use data from unknown tables and columns.

Comment: The standard practice would be to define an API (in PHP or another language) which the scripts are written and uploaded in - like a module. This is the way a modular-CMS works.

Comment: Can you provide some links for further reading? I'm not familiar with the concept